# check for naming convention in java

Tags: java, reflection

through java reflection how to check that method name is in camelCase?
e.g.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

   public class TestClass {
      private int simpleMethod(
       Object p, int x) throws NullPointerException
      {
         if (p == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
         return x;
      }

      public static void main(String args[])
      {
         try {
           Class cls = Class.forName("method1");

            Method methlist[] 
              = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (int i = 0; i < methlist.length;
               i++) {  
               Method m = methlist[i];
               System.out.println("name= " + m.getName());

            }
         }
         catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
         }
      }
   }
```

here i am getting method names simpleMethod and main 
i have to check that these names are in camelCase.

Comment: camelCase. Love the expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is ill-defined. It's easy to check if a string of letters starts with a lowercase (`[a-z][a-zA-z]*`), or to chop them up where uppercases are (see e.g. [How do I convert CamelCase into human-readable names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java/)) and verify that they are words from some given dictionary, and things like that, but unless you're told where to look for uppercases, it's almost impossible to check if a string is a semantically proper camel case or not.

- Is `bitterAFlop` a proper camel case? Maybe it should've been `bitTeraflop`?
- What about `getLinenUmber`? (Yes! ["umber"](http://www.google.co.id/search?q=define%3Aumber) is a word!)
- What about words from other languages?

Comment: What I've done to solve this is use SimpleNLG to detect words from a string, and then check if they starts with uppercase letter. 

https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg

Please check this gist to see the source:

https://gist.github.com/sergiofigueras/591c570623bb2ba142dacd9f0c1d2523

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex to check if it matches camelCase.  Related answers: [What Perl regex can match CamelCase words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815787/what-perl-regex-can-match-camelcase-words)

Comment: no that will not help me. what about these names main, getURL,etc.

Comment: How about this? [a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*

Comment: but if somebody has written simplemethod, i have to return that its not in camelCase.

Comment: Grab a dictionary. It's however going to be a lot of work. Good luck :)

Comment: In that case, you'll also have to split on the camel-case words (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773303/splitting-camelcase) and check that those words are in a dictionary.