# Utf8 correct regex for CamelCase (WikiWord) in perl

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, utf-8, camelcasing

Here was a question about the [CamelCase regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815787/what-perl-regex-can-match-camelcase-words). With the combination of [tchrist post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129) i'm wondering what is the correct **utf-8 CamelCase**.

Starting with (brian d foy's) regex:

```
/
    \b          # start at word boundary
    [A-Z]       # start with upper
    [a-zA-Z]*   # followed by any alpha

    (?:  # non-capturing grouping for alternation precedence
       [a-z][a-zA-Z]*[A-Z]   # next bit is lower, any zero or more, ending with upper
          |                     # or 
       [A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[a-z]   # next bit is upper, any zero or more, ending with lower
    )

    [a-zA-Z]*   # anything that's left
    \b          # end at word 
/x
```

and modifying to:

```
/
    \b          # start at word boundary
    \p{Uppercase_Letter}     # start with upper
    \p{Alphabetic}*          # followed by any alpha

    (?:  # non-capturing grouping for alternation precedence
       \p{Lowercase_Letter}[a-zA-Z]*\p{Uppercase_Letter}   ### next bit is lower, any zero or more, ending with upper
          |                  # or 
       \p{Uppercase_Letter}[a-zA-Z]*\p{Lowercase_Letter}   ### next bit is upper, any zero or more, ending with lower
    )

    \p{Alphabetic}*          # anything that's left
    \b          # end at word 
/x
```

Have a problem with lines marked '###'.

In addition, how to modify the regex when assuming than numbers and the underscore are equivalent to lowercase letters, so W2X3 is an valid CamelCase word.

**Updated:** (ysth comment)

for the next,

- `any`: mean "uppercase or lowercase or number or underscore"

The regex should match CamelWord, CaW

- start with uppercase letter
- optional any
- lowercase letter or number or underscore
- optional any
- upper case letter
- optional any

*Please, do not mark as duplicate, because it is not. The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815787/what-perl-regex-can-match-camelcase-words) (and answers too) thought only ascii.*

Comment: That is a really bizarre regex that you've started with; I don't think it matches anything differently than the simpler `/\b[A-Z]+[a-z][A-Za-z]*\b/`  (a "word" composed only of letters, starting with a capital letter and including at least one lower case letter) (update: I'm wrong, the original regex required at least three letters.)

Comment: in any case, please don't start with an ASCII regex; start with as precise as possible a definition of what you want to match

Comment: updated the question - with (i hope enough) precise definition

Comment: Nit: You say UTF-8 when you mean Unicode. UTF-8 is a way of storing text into bytes, but your regex is clearly meant to work on text.

Comment: That's not really my regex. [j_random_hacker came up with that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815787/what-perl-regex-can-match-camelcase-words/816598#816598), although I later modified it with the /x switch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really can’t tell what you’re trying to do, but this should be closer to what your original intent seems to have been. I still can’t tell what you mean to do with it, though.

```
m{
    \b
    \p{Upper}      #  start with uppercase code point (NOT LETTER)

    \w*            #  optional ident chars 

    # note that upper and lower are not related to letters
    (?:  \p{Lower} \w* \p{Upper}
      |  \p{Upper} \w* \p{Lower}
    )

    \w*

    \b
}x
```

Never use `[a-z]`.  And in fact, don’t use `\p{Lowercase_Letter}` or `\p{Ll}`, since those are not the same as the more desirable and more correct `\p{Lowercase}` and `\p{Lower}`.

And remember that `\w` is really just an alias for

```
[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Letter_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}]
```

Comment: Why is `Lowercase` and `Lower` more desirable? (i.e. what do they include that `Ll` doesn't?) What's the difference between `Lowercase` and `Lower` (if any)?

Comment: @ikegami: `Lowercase` and `Lower` are the same, being the union of `GC=Lowercase_Letter` with `Other_Lowercase=True`. There are 201 code points that are either ❶  `Lower` *but not* `GC=Ll`, or else ❷ `Upper` *but not* `GC=Lu`. These include `GC=Mn`, `GC=Lm`, `GC=Nl`, and `GC=So` code points. ***Sorry, I’d honestly thought this was all common knowledge by now!*** Run `unichars -gs '/(?= \P{Ll} ) \p{Lower} /x || / (?= \P{Lu} ) \p{Upper} /x' | ucsort --upper-before-lower | cat -n | less -r` to see what I mean. Those programs are in my [unicode toolchest](http://training.perl.com/scripts/).

Comment: @tchrist - the link to unicode toolset is dead (at least now). Any replacement?