# Notepad++ Regular Expression From InitCaps to UnderscoreRT

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++. I was wondering if I could change all occurences like the following from

> DONT CONVERT ALL CAPS. TextToConvert

to

> DONT CONVERT ALL CAPS. Text_To_Convert

using regular expressions in find and replace fields.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That’s awfully similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322906/utf8-correct-regex-for-camelcase-wikiword-in-perl/6323679#6323679), amongst many others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `([a-z])([A-Z])` with `\1_\2`.

Comment: Just tried it on My Notepad++, and the \1_\2 worked perfectly. I didn't know notepad++ could do that.

Comment: It worked but not in all caps. I have edited the question. Thank you :)

Comment: It shouldn't have any problems with `ALL CAPS`, make sure that "match case" is checked in the search dialog.