# Regular expression to match a string in incorrect case

Tags: regex

How do I write a regular expression that matches a particular string in all combinations of upper and lower case letters except for one?

For example, take the string "**SuperMario**". What regular expression matches that string in all *other* combinations of upper and lower case letters?

The regular expression should *match*:

- sUPERmARIO
- Supermario

The regular expression should *not match*:

- SuperMario
- Supermari

Perl compatible regular expression preferred.

Comment: sounds like an odesk job offer

Comment: Take the regex for CamelCase, and simply negate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Perl regex can match CamelCase words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815787/what-perl-regex-can-match-camelcase-words)

Comment: Why does this have to be using regular expressions?

Comment: must it be regex? what you want is case-sensitive string comparison to be false AND case-insensitive comparison to be true

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this:

```
/(?!SuperMario)(?i)supermario/
```

EDIT:

Note that you will have better performances with a lookbehind, if your string contains other things:

```
/(?i)supermario(?<!(?-i)SuperMario)/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my $s = "Supermario";
if ($s =~ /supermario/i and $s !~ /SuperMario/) {
    print "wrong\n";
}
```

Another method:

```
/(?:[S](?!uperMario)|s)[Uu][Pp][eE][rR][mM][aA][Rr][iI][oO]/
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not actually using Perl, I'm using something that accepts Perl-compatible regular expressions. Updated the question to clarify.

Comment: still, you can do case-insensitive match and also negate the result of proper form.

Comment: @JoeDaley, added an alternative

Answer (score 0):

My Perl is rusty, and this is not using regex, but how about:

```
my $term = "SuperMario";
my $input = "SuperMario";
if ( $input ne $term && uc($input) eq uc($term) ){
    print "match";
}
```